# Not able to give ring to my phone using find my device feature. Infact it is not even logging in

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pyautogui
  

gmailId="umeshbalraj12@gmail.com"
passWord="*****"
try: 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
    driver.get(r'"https://www.google.com/android/find"')
               
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.typewrite(gmailId)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.typewrite(passWord)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(x=85,y=231)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click(x=200,y=495)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrlleft', 'altleft', 'l')
  
    print('Login Successful...!!') 
except: 
    print('Login Failed')
```

Comment: I think you're confusing pyautogui with selenium's sendkeys and click functions

Comment: may i know what is the correct approach @OneCricketeer

Comment: Find the login form boxes, send keys. Send Return / Enter key, etc. All shown in the simple example https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to use pyautogui, you probably should be using tab between the email and password fields, not enter... But still, Chrome windows don't always open in the same location, so using XY coordinates likely wouldn't always work perfectly